# How can i detect circles with color

Tags: python, opencv, mask

I want to find red circles. I used opencv2, Simple Blob Detector. When i apply mask on a photo it can't find circles. It has no error messages, it just can't find any circles.
This is what i get -> [Founded_blobs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1zNs.png).
My test photo -> [BlobTest4.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9h1NB.jpg). My code is below.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=cv2.imread("BlobTest4.jpg") 
rgb=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

lower_red = np.array([95,0,0])
upper_red = np.array([255,90,90])

mask=cv2.inRange(rgb,lower_red,upper_red)

params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()

params.filterByCircularity = True
params.minCircularity = 0.85

params.minThreshold = 1
params.maxThreshold = 2000

params.filterByArea = True
params.minArea = 33

params.filterByConvexity = True
params.minConvexity = 0.8

params.filterByInertia = True
params.minInertiaRatio = 0.01

blob=cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)
blob_coordinate=blob.detect(mask)
blob_coordinate_without_mask=blob.detect(img)

founded_blobs=cv2.drawKeypoints(mask,blob_coordinate,np.array([]),(0,255,0),cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
founded_blobs_without_mask=cv2.drawKeypoints(img,blob_coordinate2,np.array([]),(0,255,0),cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

cv2.namedWindow("mask",cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.namedWindow("founded_blobs_with_mask",cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.namedWindow("founded_blobs_without_mask",cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

cv2.imshow("founded_blobs_with_mask",founded_blobs)
cv2.imshow("founded_blobs_without_mask",founded_blobs_without_mask)
cv2.imshow("mask",mask)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

Comment: Where you set all of those `SimpleBlobDetector_Params` values, do you understand what you mean? Did you try changing them to see the effect? Did you try reading the documentation in order to understand them better?

Comment: Looking at the output, it has found circles/blobs and they are outlined in green. What is the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think blob detection detects black on white ones. That's why the mask needs to be reversed.

```
reversemask=255-mask
blob=cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)
blob_coordinate=blob.detect(reversemask)
```

Here is a working code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=cv2.imread("BlobTest4.jpg")
rgb=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

lower_red = np.array([95,0,0])
upper_red = np.array([255,90,90])

hsvFrame = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

mask=cv2.inRange(rgb,lower_red,upper_red)
kernal = np.ones((5, 5), "uint8")

red_mask = cv2.dilate(mask, kernal)

params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()

params.filterByCircularity = True
params.minCircularity = 0.85

params.minThreshold = 1
params.maxThreshold = 2000

params.filterByArea = True
params.minArea = 33

params.filterByConvexity = True
params.minConvexity = 0.8

params.filterByInertia = True
params.minInertiaRatio = 0.01

reversemask=255-mask

blob=cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)
blob_coordinate=blob.detect(reversemask)

blob_coordinate_without_mask=blob.detect(img)
print(blob_coordinate_without_mask)
print(blob_coordinate)
founded_blobs=cv2.drawKeypoints(red_mask,blob_coordinate,np.array([]),(0,255,0),cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
founded_blobs_without_mask=cv2.drawKeypoints(img,blob_coordinate_without_mask,np.array([]),(0,255,0),cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

cv2.namedWindow("mask",cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.namedWindow("founded_blobs_with_mask",cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.namedWindow("founded_blobs_without_mask",cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

cv2.imshow("founded_blobs_with_mask",founded_blobs)
cv2.imshow("founded_blobs_without_mask",founded_blobs_without_mask)
cv2.imshow("mask",mask)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```